# What is the difference between "laravel create blog" and "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

In laravel 5, We can create a new project using `laravel create blog` or using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`. 
Is there any difference between these commands? 
Which one is efficient?
 Which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run the command

```
laravel new blog
```

You need to have the laravel installer globally available.

So

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Run the above command once and you will be ready to use the laravel new blog command for the rest of the life time. This method is fast and installs all dependencies.

Now for the second method:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} "~5.1.0" --prefer-dist
```

You gotta be running this command everytime and update the dependencies to its latest one.

So overall, `laravel new blog` would be the fastest and most efficient approach since you have the laravel installer available globally.

You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation

Comment: Why are you referring specifically to Laravel 5.0, here? The OP has made a specific reference to version 5.1 by means of the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `laravel create blog` because according to the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master#installation `laravel new blog` it's much faster than installing via Composer.

Of course you can use either one or the other. Any of the two will be fine